# Is a contraction idempotent operator one-to-one?

Tags: functional-analysis

Is a contraction idempotent operator one-to-one?
In the other words, if $T:H\to H$ is a bounded linear operator such that $\|T\|\le 1$, can we conclude $T$ is an injective operator?

Comment: First of all, you must exclude $T=0$...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, no. Take $T=0$.

Moreover, any orthogonal projector $P^2=P\ne I$ in that space is idempotent yet not injective.